# Problem with WireGuard/tun module after updating Kubuntu to 22.10

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, vpn, wireguard, 22.10

After updating my kubuntu (after that I rebooted my device) to 22.10 from 22.04 I am unable to run the wire guard:

```
sudo wg-quick up wg0
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.77.28.148 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
Failed to resolve interface "tun": No such device
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
```

I'm assuming that since WireGuard was working with the previous version of the operating system, its configuration is correct (but maybe it's a wrong assumption...), so I guess there is a problem with the tun module. When I try to check this module with `lsmod | grep 'tun'` I doesn't see output for it. `sudo modprobe tun` doesn't change anything. I also can't find the `tun.ko.gz` in the `/lib/modules/` directory, I only see `qrtr-tun.ko`.

`modinfo tun` returns:

```
name:           tun
filename:       (builtin)
alias:          devname:net/tun
alias:          char-major-10-200
license:        GPL
file:           drivers/net/tun
author:         (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
description:    Universal TUN/TAP device driver
```

`grep "CONFIG_TUN" -r /usr/src` returns:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-23-generic/.config:CONFIG_TUN=y
```

If you need any more information, please let me know. Also, sorry if anything that I provide above is irrelevant, this topic is quite new to me.

Comment: Have you checked the WireGuard web site to see if 22.10 is supported?

Comment: Place your wireguard script into /etc/wireguard/tun0.conf, and use `sudo wg-quick up tun0`. See `man wg-quick` or `man wg`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. It seems to be a problem with the update(r) to Ubuntu 22.10 (my system was on 22.04).

I was able to fix it executing `sudo apt purge resolvconf`

Please note that I don't know if this could cause additional problems, but it worked for getting wireguard running again. Ubuntu is using systemd-resolved and normally resolvconf should only be a "link" to systemd-resolved.

Additional information may be found [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireguard/+bug/1992491)

Removing the DNS declaration in your .conf file will work to, but this is not an acceptable solution if you want to use a custom DNS server over wireguard.

Answer (score 0):

In my wg0.conf file, I commented out the DNS line (because I don't like deleting anything if I can help it) and then added

```
PostUp = resolvectl dns %i *DNS IP ADDRESS*
```

to the end of my interface block

Answer (score -1):

Comment or remove your DNS key in wireguard client config file

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3um9.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).